# Domain account for LDAP authentication without change ability

Tags: active-directory

I have set up a [Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for our small  local domain (abc.local) on a linux VM (just for internal use).  Our local domain controller is a Win Server 2008 R2. I've setup the Mediawiki [LDAP Authentication extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAPAuthentication2) so that i can restrict editing of our Wiki to only domain Users.  I've configured the Mediawiki LDAP configuration to use the domain Administrator credentials for this authentication.

Is there a way to create another account that can do this user authentication but can't change anything?  Sort of like a "read-only" Administrator account?

thanks,
russ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An account can't be "read-only" and also "Administrator". It's one or the other.

"Authentication" can only ever be done with the user's own credentials. There is no special kind of account that lets you authenticate other accounts. All it needs credentials for is to look up accounts on the domain. So you only need a read-only account, which is basically any account that can authenticate on your domain.

So just create an account specifically for Mediawiki and use that.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.  By default my new user is in the Users group.  I moved it to the RDOC (Read-Only Domain Controllers) and took it out of Users.  Is that a problem?  Or, should i make a new group with only this 1 new user as member - e.g. a group named `CantDoAnything`?

Comment: It doesn't matter which group the user is in. It just needs to be a valid user on the domain so the DC can say "I know who you are".